# Suggested edits queue for a question I edited and profile reflect different stats on the number of questions I have edited

Tags: support, bug, review, suggested-edits, profile-page

(I think my question is different than [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354774/inconsistencies-in-posts-edited-count) because that is asking for help in a specific example about deleted posts while I am asking about inconsistency in general.)

In the suggested edits queue for a question I edited, I noticed that my stats looked like this: [image]

But in my profile, I see this:

[image]

The editor stats say I have edited 42 posts, but my profile says I have edited 37 posts.

Why is this?

Comment: [Duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Ameta.stackexchange.com+number+posts+edited+vs+suggestions+approved) of [Inconsistencies in posts edited count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354774/289905).

Comment: @SebastianSimon I think my question is different than that one because that is asking for help in a specific example about deleted posts while I am asking about inconsistency in general.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's ... complicated.

37 posts edited indicates the number of *distinct* posts where you've edited *the body or title*, except your own posts. 42 is simply the number of your suggested edits that have been approved.

- If you edit, or suggest an edit to a post twice, that will count two times in the number of edit suggestions, but only once in the number of posts edited. As far as I can see, that hasn't happened.
- If you [only edit the tags of a question](https://writing.stackexchange.com/posts/54425/revisions), that will count towards the number of edit suggestions, but not towards the number of edited posts.
- If a post you suggested an edit on has been deleted, the number of posts edited won't reflect that, but it does count for the number of edit suggestions. I have no way to check this.

Comment: It's actually way more complicated, see my updated answer...

Comment: You're welcome. I might have forgotten about one or two edge cases, but I'm sure other users here will correct me :)